# Reading a file line by line for large files efficiently in PHP?

Tags: php, performance

My app reads a large file 5MB - 10MB that has been entered in with json entries line by line.

Each line is handled by a parser that is fed to multiple parsers and treated separately. Once the file is read, the file is moved. The Program is continuously fed with files to be processed.

The program currently works with `@file_get_contents($filename)`. The program's structure works as is.

The problem is that `file_get_contents` loads the entire file as an array and the entire system runs for a minute. I suspect that I can gain speed if I read it line by line rather than wait for the file to load into memory (I might be wrong and open to suggestion).

There are too many file handler that does this. What is the most effective way to achieve what I need and which file reading method is best for this?

I have `fopen`, `fread`, `readfile`, `file`, and `fscanf` to contend with off the top of my head. However when I read the man for them - its all code to read generic files without a clear indication what is best for larger files.

Comment: y don't u use [The SplFileObject class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.splfileobject.php#class.splfileobject)?

Comment: reason to use it? is it faster than to write those file function?

Answer (score 3):

```
$file = fopen("file.json", "r");

if ($file)
{
    while (($line = fgets($file)) !== false) 
    {
        echo $line;
    }
}
else 
{
    echo "Unable to open the file";
}
```

Fgets read until it reach EOL, or EOF. if you want, you can add how much it should read using the second arg.

For more info about fgets: https://www.php.net/fgets

Comment: ok but is it the most efficient of the bunch to read large files and single line, what makes it different and more effective than fread or readfile...etc

Comment: This is the best way when you need to read every line without keep them in memory . Other way is to use fread but it's the same and I never noticed any differences (well I found fgets more easy to write too but it's me) Maybe someone else will post a fread version, I can't now sorry.