# How to quickly scan large text file for a domain name? (Laravel, PHP)

Tags: php, laravel

I have a large text file which is checked against for "bad urls". While processing a bunch of urls against this list, it takes about 1 second per url to verify it's not in that list.

Here's my current code:

```
$badDomainsFile = file_get_contents(base_path().'/resources/txt/bad-domains.txt');
$badDomains = explode("\n",$badDomainsFile);
foreach ($badDomains as $badDomain){
   if($badDomain===$domain){
      $isBadDomain = true;
      break;
   }
}
```

I thought maybe I could speed things up with some exec('grep -n $path') style code, but I'm having trouble getting it to work on my local machine (windows) and I believe the file path will be different on the server (linux) anyway? Everything in laravel on my local machine is run through Homestead but I'm also confused if maybe the php script would be running against that file path or my own local systems location of the website?

Any other ideas to speed up this script? (I tried running a line-by-line fgets() style script but that took up to 11 seconds per url.)

Comment: I don't think `file_get_contents` and `explode` are optimized for this use case. Could you try this solution to see if the performances are improved? https://stackoverflow.com/a/22456681/8068675

Comment: I have tried that solution, it was slower in my case (up to 11 seconds per url). I've opted to import the list into a database table to speed up performance. Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A scalable solution would be to keep the list in a database (MySQL or whatever you are using for the rest of the application) and let the engine take care of optimizations. Any decent DB engine will allow indexing and caching the list out-of-the-box. Thus, reducing the load time and speeding up the search.

When you are reading from a file, every time the entire file is loaded from the disk and a full-scan is performed. This operation has a complexity of `O(n)`

When reading from an indexed list with unique items, the complexity is `O(1)`

Even if the list grows into billions of items, the impact on search speed will be negligible.

Answer (score 1):

You are reading from file. You could try to read it once and store in some kind of cache instead like memcached or redis. It should give you better performance.